# Cant' dismiss a UISearchContainerViewController on tvos

Tags: swift, tvos, uisearchcontroller, childviewcontroller

So I'm working on a full screen tvos video application.  No Tab bar, No Navigation Bar.
I've been trying to add Search functionality to this app.
I'm using a gesture during development to display the search feature.

I instantiate the results controller from my storyboard, then programmatically add that results ViewController to a UISearchController and then wrap that in a UISearchContainerViewController.
I then add that UISearchContainerViewController to my parent ViewController via:  addChildViewController, set frame, view.addSubview, didMoveToParentViewController....
(per https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

This successfully displays a functional search controller full screen over my now paused video.

BUT, when I try to dismiss the search ViewController it won't go away...........
I attempt to dismiss the UISearchContainerViewController via:  willMoveToParentViewController(nil), view.removeFromSuperView() and removeFromParentViewController...  The view does not disappear...

I've verified that the gestures are being called... and I've gone so far as to verify that the parents childViewController no longer contains the UISearchContainerViewController... but the Search interface remains??

I've simply hiding the UISearchContainerViewController for grins... it does not go away!?

I'm going to try a modal presentation as a fallback, but it's not the desired solution... and now I'm personally bugged as to why this doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.